# can't run pip3 on cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, pip, pyvenv

I can't use pip3 in venv (on cygwin), but why?
I may be able to use it out of venv.

```
(tensorflow)
MYNAME@DESKTOP-O27QMD1 ~
$ apt-cyg install python3-pip
Package python3-pip is already installed, skipping

(tensorflow)
MYNAME@DESKTOP-O27QMD1 ~/tensorflow/bin
$ ls
activate      activate.fish  easy_install-3.6  pip3    python
activate.csh  easy_install   pip               pip3.6  python3

(tensorflow)
MYNAME@DESKTOP-O27QMD1 ~
$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
-bash: /home/MYNAME/tensorflow/bin/pip3: "/home/MYNAME: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: not sure, but maybe naming your venv something other than tensorflow will help..?

Comment: there is something very badly b0rken here. The shebang line of `/home/MYNAME/tensorflow/bin/pip3` is probably something like `#!/home/MYNAME` - and that's it

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow` to explicitly use the installed pip command.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing python3-pip and the installing it again:

```
apt-cyg remove python3-pip
apt-cyg install python3-pip
```

I ran into this issue when trying to upgrade my version of pip3. It fails during the uninstall of the older version so it's only partially uninstalled.